# How to organize time_stamps with values in lua?

Tags: lua

Create something like array of values associated with time_stamps, and getting values by time_stamps. only one value with one time_stamp. How better organise it? And how to remove values after goes  some time?

something like this:

```
datetime = os.date("!*t",os.time())

array[datetime]=somevalue
```

And how to delete from that table values older than 10 minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why using the date table as keys. You can instead use the timestamp directly as keys, something like:

```
t[os.time()] = somevalue
```

The timestamps are only integer values, you can get its real date with `os.date` when in need.

You can compare them directly. For instance, to remove values that is before May 20, 2014, compare the keys with `os.time{year=2014, month=5, day=20, hour=0}`.

Comment: And to remove older than 10 minutes, compare keys with: os.time()-600